# disable adblock in chrome or any other browser using blog

Tags: ads, adblock

my blog stuffloot.com [a complete blog[enter link description here][1](http://www.stuffloot.com) want to disbale adblocker in chrome.for eg when a user open my website,the ad shown on my website will not be disabled by chrome or any other browser](http://www.stuffloot.com)

www.stuffloot.com

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to "disable" a user's plugins. Nor is there a way to return a list of which plugins a user has installed.

You can however block (most) adblockers from accessing your website.

The easiest way to block adblockers is to use a simple JavaScript to detect a commonly blocked element.

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if ( typeof(window.google_jobrunner) === "undefined" ) {
        console.log("ad blocker installed");
      } else {
        console.log("no ad blocking found.");
      }
    }, 10000);  
  };
</script>
```

Or, even easier:

Use the free anti-Adblock script generator at http://blockadblock.com/configure.php